# SugarCRM CE 6.5.20 Ubuntu 14.04 MySQL "Cannot Load DB Manager"

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, sugarcrm

I am currently following the installation wizard for the SugarCRM Community addition. I am now on the step where I link to the MySQL database that I have set up on my Ubuntu server. However I am getting the specific error:

```
Cannot load DB manager
* Required field
```

There is no other information beyond this and googling is yielding zero results.

Answer (score 0):

First I got another error about the database and I solved it. Then appears this message "Cannot load DB manager *Required field" then .... 
I only went back once through the arrows then I clicked next and I could go to next screen, "Confirm Settings". The error doesn't appeared anymore.